# Simple Network Connection issue

Tags: windows-xp, networking, lan

Using Windows XP, all Notebooks (HP6910p) are connected to switch through cables. Cables are okay/tested and working perfectly. All of computers are automatically being assigned an IP on network 192.168.1.XXX.

When yesterday I formatted one notebook's window and installed drivers. Everything is good, on LAN, internet is also working perfectly, newly installed window pings other notebooks perfectly and other notebooks can ping newly installed window machine also.

However when I try to access/browse other machine on LAN it is not. Neither newly installed window open other machine NOR others can open newly installed windows machine. When I try to access from *run* command like `"\\192.168.1.XXX"` it simple display error alert "the network computer cannot be accessed blah blah", very quickly.  Why is it not working?

NB: All at same default "WORKGROUP".

Comment: Just tried to "Repair" network by right clicking on system tray icon and when tried to repair the network by system; it says "windows could not finish repairing the problem because the following actions cannot be completed [Clearing NetBT]". This message is appearing with yellow icon.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure network/printer sharing is enabled for the "new" machine's network connection? Also make sure it's not blocked by the Windows Firewall (or any other firewall).

Comment: Yes it is sure that Windows Firewall is disabled on all the machines and would you more elaborate "network/printer sharing is enabled for the new mahcine's network"... on which machine this needs to be enable for new machine?

Comment: Just tried to "Repair" network by right clicking on system tray icon and when tried o repaired the network by system it says "windows could not finish repairing the problem because the folloing actions cannot be completed [Clearing NetBT]". This message is appearing with yellow icon

Comment: On all, those accessing and those being accessed. It can be found in the properties of the network Connections amongst TCP/IP and other things.